# How should I handle cron jobs on nodester?

Tags: node.js, nodester

I'd like to watch for certain changes on a couchdb in a NodeJS app, currently hosted on Nodester.

Is it OK to just open long polling sockets or use setTimeout() in a Nodester app?  Or is there some typical way people handle this on Nodester or similar hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js apps are long running processes by nature, so you can handle these problems in the process.

I would see no problem in using `setInterval` to either run the task on a fixed interval or check a task queue on a fixed interval. This should work just fine.

Any questions let me know.